# How to extract and populate data based on two matching cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying extract data based on matching 2 cells.  Can anyone help me with the formula?

For Example: If data in C1 = B3 then

Populate

```
b4     c4
b5     c5
b6     c6
...
```

Comment: Populate with what?  in b4 you could put `=if(c1=B3,1,0)`  but I don't know, nor do I believe others will know, what you want in those other cells...  or to handle blanks... `=IF(AND(C1=B3,C1<>""),1,0)`

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(AND(C1=B3,C1<>""),1,0)`

Without knowing what values you want in the populated cells I'm not sure how to answer... however the basic formula is above...
and example image below:

[image]

Comment: This is the table i am trying to replicate

Comment: This is the table i am trying to replicate Manufacturer  C1=DELTA  
    
 B3=DELTA   
 LY  TY 
Row Labels Sum of Sales $ Sum of Units Sum of Sales $ Sum of Units
3M  26,312,826   6,733,824   20,999,561   4,811,066 
DOW  23,712,557   4,798,246   21,037,383   4,175,047 
HIGH RIDGE  2,033,626   818,254   428,445   187,106 
KOHLEN  24,443,221   7,592,083   24,391,780   7,597,468 
….. B3 DYNAMIC DATA

Comment: This is better off as a table or screenshot in your original post.